# How do download file save as a dialog box in internet Explore via asp.net

Tags: javascript, html

In my project I have implemented a link with . It's working fine in Chrome Browser. But now I need to implement it the same way in internet Explorer. I tried a lot onclick button with `document.execCommand("SaveAs", false, "");` but didn't exactly get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **Content-Disposition: attachment** property in your code. Like,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition: attachment", "filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
```